# Saving scenarios in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have to build a shiny application where  when the user logs (as an example) he will see this app: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/tabsets.html
[image]

Now the user may want to save each combination of user inputs as one scenario. For eg: 1st scenario might be distribution type normal and the number of observation 100. 2nd Scenario might be distribution type uniform and number of observations 200. Now once the user saves the scenario and names them. When he logs back in he should be able to see the scenarios under a scenarios page. Does anyone have any suggestions/examples on what might the right approach? Would it be to use the bookmarking state and save that into a database and retrieve it based on the user logged in?

Comment: Bookmarking + database is a reasonable approach. You'll need to get the URL with a custom callback function using `onBookmarked` (as you may already know). For further information see [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/advanced-bookmarking.html)

Comment: Why don't you just save a CSV file with one user per row and save the scenario everytime a user changes the scenario? Unless you need something more sophisticated.